# Design Suggestions on side bar navigation

Tags: navigation, visual-design

This side bar navigation lets users click on a specific graph and it takes them by having the webpage scroll to that graph. Any Visual Design suggestions to make the side bar look better. The white is used as non clickable text where as the orange is used as clickable text. Any color suggestion to change for the clickable text.Also how to separate each graph title because due to their long name its hard to put them on one line and have them be more seperate. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

- Separating each list item in the nav visually in order to create a better on-page information architecture
- Organizing the information into a hierarchy. For example, all response time items could come under one heading and all volume types could come under another heading. This would allow you to have shorter list items and reduce redundant information by improving the 'data to ink' ratio

See the example below for reference:

[image]